# Unable to list data sent with push

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

[[image]]

> I have 3 recording screens and I want to list user information on a single page.But each is assigned a separate pushKey. I also can't use these pushKeys to access the database in the code section

```
{
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const db = firebase.database();

  const ref = db.ref('kullaniciBilgiler/'+`${user}`);
  
  
 
    ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
       var data=snapshot.val();
      console.log(data)
      
    }, (errorObject) => {
      console.log('The read failed: ' + errorObject.name);
    });

  

   
 


export default class profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }



  render() {


    var box = [];

    for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
  
      box.push(

        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <View style={styles.textBox}>
          <Text style={styles.textMid}>Soyisim</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>                     
            <TextInput                         
             onChangeText={(text)=>setList(text)}
              style={styles.input}
           />
        </View>    
        </View>
      
      )
    }
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} >
       
        <View style={styles.profilePhoto}>
         <Image 
         style={{
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          resizeMode: 'contain',
          marginTop:40
        }}
        source={
          require('../../image/logo.png')
        }
         
         />

        </View>
        <View style={styles.profileDetails}>
                  
    {box}
                    

   </View>
                  
          
      </SafeAreaView>
      </ScrollView>
    );    
  }
}
}
```

**I can't get random keys assigned by push and I can't access information from the database**

[[image]]

```
_handleSubmit = (values) => {


auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
  .then(() => {
    userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    if (userId) {
      var database = firebase.database().ref('kullaniciBilgiler/').child(userId).push();
      database.set({
        name: values.name,
        surname: values.surname,
        email: values.email,

      }).then(() => console.log('okey'));
    }
```

> This register code

Comment: Database image is located in the link at the top

Comment: You should use `.set()` instead of `.push()` so all of user's information is right under the user UID node. Can you share your code that includes `push()`ing the data to Firebase?

Comment: Of course , one minute pls

Comment: https://dosya.co/yex1g5cf8q97/Ekran_Alıntıs1ı.PNG.html
this register code

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add it as text so it's easier to copy and explain?

Comment: sorry uptade now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a new user is created by `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, set all of user's data right under the UID node instead of pushing new nodes. This can be done by using `set()` instead of `push()`:

```js
const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

const database = firebase.database().ref('kullaniciBilgiler/' + userId)

database.set({
  name: values.name,
  surname: values.surname,
  email: values.email,
}).then(() => console.log('okey'));

// similarly use 'update()' when adding other fields later
```

When you query user's node, it should now return an object like this:

```
{
  name: '',
  surname: '',
  email: '',
  age: 0,
  ...otherFields
}
```

You can read more about updating data in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data).

Comment: ı use formik-yup

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't solve the problem because, as I said above, I have a recording system consisting of 3 different screens and instead of adding it, it deletes and prints only the information on that page

Comment: @TuranBicav you should use `update()` to add new fields thereafter so existing data is not deleted. Can you update your question with the code that you used to update other fields?

Comment: Thank you so much, how could I not have thought of that in 3 days.I wonder if I'm mad at myself.